# Branch Prediction: Writing Code to Understand it; Getting Weird Results

Tags: c++, branch-prediction

I'm trying to get a good understanding of branch prediction by measuring the time to run loops with predictable branches vs. loops with random branches.

So I wrote a program that takes large arrays of 0's and 1's arranged in different orders (i.e. all 0's, repeating 0-1, all rand), and iterates through the array branching based on if the current index is 0 or 1, doing time-wasting work.

I expected that harder-to-guess arrays would take longer to run on, since the branch predictor would guess wrong more often, and that the time-delta between runs on two sets of arrays would remain the same regardless of the amount of time-wasting work.

However, as amount of time-wasting work increased, the difference in time-to-run between arrays increased, A LOT.

[image: Yo this graph makes no sense]

(X-axis is amount of time-wasting work, Y-axis is time-to-run)

Does anyone understand this behavior? You can see the code I'm running at the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
static const int s_iArrayLen = 999999;
static const int s_iMaxPipelineLen = 60;
static const int s_iNumTrials = 10;

int doWorkAndReturnMicrosecondsElapsed(int* vals, int pipelineLen){
        int* zeroNums = new int[pipelineLen];
        int* oneNums = new int[pipelineLen];
        for(int i = 0; i < pipelineLen; ++i)
                zeroNums[i] = oneNums[i] = 0;

        chrono::time_point<chrono::system_clock> start, end;
        start = chrono::system_clock::now();
        for(int i = 0; i < s_iArrayLen; ++i){
                if(vals[i] == 0){
                        for(int i = 0; i < pipelineLen; ++i)
                                ++zeroNums[i];
                }
                else{
                        for(int i = 0; i < pipelineLen; ++i)
                                ++oneNums[i];
                }
        }
        end = chrono::system_clock::now();
        int elapsedMicroseconds = (int)chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end-start).count();

        //This should never fire, it just exists to guarantee the compiler doesn't compile out our zeroNums/oneNums
        for(int i = 0; i < pipelineLen - 1; ++i)
                if(zeroNums[i] != zeroNums[i+1] || oneNums[i] != oneNums[i+1])
                        return -1;
        delete[] zeroNums;
        delete[] oneNums;
        return elapsedMicroseconds;
}

struct TestMethod{
        string name;
        void (*func)(int, int&);
        int* results;

        TestMethod(string _name, void (*_func)(int, int&)) { name = _name; func = _func; results = new int[s_iMaxPipelineLen]; }
};

int main(){
        srand( (unsigned int)time(nullptr) );

        vector<TestMethod> testMethods;
        testMethods.push_back(TestMethod("all-zero", [](int index, int& out) { out = 0; } ));
        testMethods.push_back(TestMethod("repeat-0-1", [](int index, int& out) { out = index % 2; } ));
        testMethods.push_back(TestMethod("repeat-0-0-0-1", [](int index, int& out) { out = (index % 4 == 0) ? 0 : 1; } ));
        testMethods.push_back(TestMethod("rand", [](int index, int& out) { out = rand() % 2; } ));

        int* vals = new int[s_iArrayLen];

        for(int currentPipelineLen = 0; currentPipelineLen < s_iMaxPipelineLen; ++currentPipelineLen){
                for(int currentMethod = 0; currentMethod < (int)testMethods.size(); ++currentMethod){
                        int resultsSum = 0;
                        for(int trialNum = 0; trialNum < s_iNumTrials; ++trialNum){
                                //Generate a new array...
                                for(int i = 0; i < s_iArrayLen; ++i)  
                                        testMethods[currentMethod].func(i, vals[i]);

                                //And record how long it takes
                                resultsSum += doWorkAndReturnMicrosecondsElapsed(vals, currentPipelineLen);
                        }

                        testMethods[currentMethod].results[currentPipelineLen] = (resultsSum / s_iNumTrials);
                }
        }

        cout << "\t";
        for(int i = 0; i < s_iMaxPipelineLen; ++i){
                cout << i << "\t";
        }
        cout << "\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)testMethods.size(); ++i){
                cout << testMethods[i].name.c_str() << "\t";
                for(int j = 0; j < s_iMaxPipelineLen; ++j){
                        cout << testMethods[i].results[j] << "\t";
                }
                cout << "\n";
        }
        int end;
        cin >> end;
        delete[] vals;
}
```

Pastebin link: http://pastebin.com/F0JAu3uw

Comment: Shouldn't `out = rand();` be `out = rand() % 2;`?

Comment: Oh, jeez, David, that was a dumb mistake on my part. Edited and updated with new data -- that explains why the random array took less time than the other arrays.

Comment: This wavy pattern is also interesting.

Comment: BTW what type of CPU was benchmarked?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you may be measuring the cache/memory performance, more than the branch prediction. Your inner 'work' loop is accessing an ever increasing chunk of memory. Which may explain the linear growth, the periodic behaviour, etc.

I could be wrong, as I've not tried replicating your results, but if I were you I'd factor out memory accesses before timing other things. Perhaps sum one volatile variable into another, rather than working in an array.

Note also that, depending on the CPU, the branch prediction can be a lot smarter than just recording the last time a branch was taken - repeating patterns, for example, aren't as bad as random data.

Ok, a quick and dirty test I knocked up on my tea break which tried to mirror your own test method, but without thrashing the cache, looks like this:

[image]

Is that more what you expected?

If I can spare any time later there's something else I want to try, as I've not really looked at what the compiler is doing...

**Edit:**

And, here's my final test - I recoded it in assembler to remove the loop branching, ensure an exact number of instructions in each path, etc.

[image: More branch prediction results]

I also added an extra case, of a 5-bit repeating pattern. It seems pretty hard to upset the branch predictor on my ageing Xeon.

Comment: +1 for actually trying it yourself - I take the "111" in the legend is just as good as "1" (i.e. always "1")? If so, that doesn't seem *that* interesting given that you already checked the "always zero" case (and indeed, the two graphs are basically the same).

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Actually that should be '0111', but Excel truncated the label as it turned the text into a number...

Comment: Oh my, those are gorgeous results -- yes, that is exactly what I expected to see (well, I expected to see all lines have the same slope, not necessarily the fact the branch predictor is smart enough about repeating patterns to spend equal amounts time on all of them). Thanks for the informative answer!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what JasonD pointed out, I would also like to note that there are conditions inside `for` loop, which may affect branch predictioning:

```
if(vals[i] == 0)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < pipelineLen; ++i)
        ++zeroNums[i];
}
```

**i < pipelineLen;** is a condition like your `if`s. Of course compiler may unroll this loop, however pipelineLen is argument passed to a function so probably it does not.

I'm not sure if this can explain wavy pattern of your results, but:

> Since the BTB is only 16 entries long in the Pentium 4 processor, the prediction will eventually fail for loops that are longer than 16 iterations. This limitation can be avoided by unrolling a loop until it is only 16 iterations long. When this is done, a loop conditional will always fit into the BTB, and a branch misprediction will not occur on loop exit. The following is an exam ple of loop unrolling:

Read full article: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/branch-and-loop-reorganization-to-prevent-mispredicts

So your loops are not only measuring memory throughput but they are also affecting BTB.

If you have passed `0-1` pattern in your list but then executed a for loop with `pipelineLen = 2` your BTB will be filled with something like `0-1-1-0 - 1-1-1-0 - 0-1-1-0 - 1-1-1-0` and  then it will start to overlap, so this can indeed explain wavy pattern of your results (some overlaps will be more harmful than others).

Take this as an example of what may happen rather than literal explanation. Your CPU may have much more sophisticated branch prediction architecture.

Comment: Bear in mind that, as the text you quote points out, that "16 entry BTB" refers to the Pentium 4. More modern processors have more advanced branch prediction logic.

Comment: @JasonD of course, I don't know what type of CPU you have. Take this as an example of what may happen. BTBs are still operating on the same principle. Sandy Bridge for example has single BTB. Article from Intel is from 2011 so I guess it still applies to newer architectures.

Comment: Yes, and you're correct that if you want to measure the branch prediction in isolation, it's definitely worth eliminating branches for loops, etc. On my local CPU, it cleans up the results a bit but otherwise doesn't have a big impact. On the OP's CPU it might have a more profound effect.

Comment: @JasonD that's what I want to express. Paradoxically to measure performance of your system reliably you have to know its architecture quite well. Otherwise side-effects may disrupt your results.